# Keep div aspect ratio when resizing

Tags: html, css

I want to keep the aspect ration of a div when the browser resizes.

I've had this problem before and then the solution was using `padding-bottom` with a percentage.

e.q. if I want a div with class `foo` to have the aspect ratio `2:1` i'll have some css that looks like this.

```
.foo{
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

the math `(height/width)*100 = percentage` in this case `(2/1)*100 = 50%`. If you want a div with the aspect ratio of `16:9` the math is `(9/16)*100 = 56.25%` etc.

This has worked for me before but now It doesn't.
I have the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hpmu8wh0/1/) so you can see what I mean.

It seems `.caption-wrap` has a height but I don't know where it's coming from.

Comment: The extra height belons to the height of the contents. I.e. the contents should be positioned absolutely in order not to affect the computed height.

Comment: @HashemQolami something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hpmu8wh0/2/)?

Comment: Did you try to use height:0 for .caption-wrap ?

Comment: Almost, and give `overflow: hidden;` to the wrapper if it's needed.

Comment: @HashemQolami I want the content to be responsive, but that's material for another question. could you put it in an answer?

Comment: Also note that a percentage top/bottom padding/margin is relative to the width of the containing block, not the box itself! hence in your online example you should use a value of `63% / 2` instead.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped, but I tend to leave it as a comment because there are couple of (exact) similar questions/answers posted before :) But if you feel it would help the upcoming readers, it is good to post it as the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this example :

```
/*
 * Pure CSS aspect ratio with no spacer images or js! :)
 */

body {
    width: 36%;
    margin: 8px auto;
}

div.stretchy-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    position: relative;

    background: blue;
}

div.stretchy-wrapper > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;

    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Other aspect ratios to try:
 * 56.25% = 16:9
 * 75% = 4:3
 * 66.66% = 3:2
 * 62.5% = 8:5
 */
```

Link to dabblet : http://dabblet.com/gist/2590942